# 1st statement in try block not executed

Tags: android

While testing my code for android app, I noticed that the 1st statement in try block is not executed.
Here is my code.

```
try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "try block start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TRY after sleep", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("123", null, "ddd", null, null);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EXCEPTION CATCH", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
    }
```

The 1st toast "try block start" is shown at all.

Any idea where am I mistaking please?

Comment: Never `sleep` on UI thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `Thread.sleep(5000);` line. By using sleep on the main thread (which is the UI thread), you're actually stop drawing the UI for 5 sec (which exceeds the time of the Toast show).

You should avoid from using sleep on the UI thread (since it will cause your UI to hang).

Comment: @m0skit0 I added some explanation.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. *"You should generally avoid from using sleep on the UI thread"* I would say **never** use sleep in UI thread, just makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you are sleeping for 5 seconds. 
Your UI thread is hanging and can not draw the Toast. 
When the time of the sleep passes, your toast time would also have passed. Try `Thread.sleep(500);` instead.

Finally, do not use Thread.sleep() on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "try block start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It will run on UI thread. If you are in a background thead with Android 4.0 than the show() will throw an exception.